# Access IIF statement to list results

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, iif-function

In Access 2010 I'm trying to list the results from my IIF statement but for some reason is not working.

```
DogTrainingStatus: IIf(([TrainingSuccess]>"*Pass*") And ([TrainingSuccess]>"*Failed*"),"Failed", IIf([TrainingSuccess]>"Failed","Failed"," "))
```

This is my list:

```
DogGroups - TrainingSuccess  
---------------------------  
A         - Pass, Pass, Pass  
B         - Pass, Pass, Failed  
C         - (Blank)  
D         - Failed, Failed, Failed
```

I need the following results:

```
DogGroups - TrainingSuccess  
---------------------------  
A         - Pass  
B         - Failed  
C         - (Blank)  
D         - Failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming field holds CSV text and the result you want follows logic: if field is Null, return Null, otherwise if field contains "Failed" return "Failed", otherwise "Passed", consider:

`DogTrainingStatus: IIf([TrainingSuccess] Is Null, Null, IIf([TrainingSuccess] LIKE "*Failed*", "Failed", "Passed"))`

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually, the text is a concat then made into a table which is used as part of my query. You're suggestion of using "Is Null" is Null and  "Like" worked with success. I don't know why I didn't think of "Like" my brain just kept thinking of the math symbols which if I think about what I'm doing or what I'm not doing which is not math. Thank you again!